# Powershell : Backup-SqlDatabase -ExpirationDate

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-backups

I try to use the snap-in Backup-SqlDatabase with an expirationDate, and I get an error :
invalid value for the parameter EXPIREDATE.
Can someone tell me how to format this parameter ?

Here's my code :

```
$expirationDate = Get-Date
$expirationDate = $expirationDate.AddDays($expirationDelayInDays)

Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database -ConnectionTimeout 0 -BackupFile $outputFile -ExpirationDate $expirationDate
```

Comment: According to the documentation expirationdate should be of type DateTime. However, it seems you're not updating the $expirationDate on your second line. Could you try: `$expirationdate = $expirationdate.adddays($expirationDelayInDays)`

Comment: You're right, I changed the code... not better.
$expirationDate is DateTime I believe.

Comment: Strange as the code works for me, what value are you using for the variable $expirationDelayInDays?  It may be that rather than a formatting issue, the value you are passing is indeed invalid as a datetime is definitely the only type this parameter will accept.

Comment: I use 7 for $expirationDelayInDays.
To me $expirationDate is a datetime, am I wrong ?

Comment: OK. It seems that $expirationdate should not be of DateTime type !
... but a string that can be converted into a datetime.
When using $expidationdate = "2013-09-01" it works...but I believe there is a bug in the convesion so that 09 and 01 are inverted.

Comment: You'll say "Well done, no problem if I know"... And you'll be wrong because :
$expidationdate = "2013-13-01" will be rejected because it is not a valid date for Powershell.
$expidationdate = "2013-01-13" will be rejected by SQL Server because of the inversion !

So, It seems it's impossible to have an expiration date after the 12th of a month

Answer (score 1):

`EXPIREDATE` only handles *dates*. It does not handle *time* components.
Therefore, you need to specify a `DateTime` with an empty time component (using the `DateTime.Date` property):

```
$expirationDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($expirationDelayInDays).Date
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $instance -Database $database -ExpirationDate $expirationDate
```