# c# SMO Backup - how to use ExpirationDate?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, smo

I followed roughly [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798407/backing-up-database-with-smo) to backup a database with Microsofts SMO API and the code crashed with an exception telling `invalid parameter ExpirationDate`. I checked [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.expirationdate?view=sqlserver-2016) which does not contain details on how to set the parameter and my intuition told me it should be in the future, right? I was curious and tested some values:

1. DateTime.Today.AddDays(10) -> InvalidDataException
2. DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10) -> works fine
3. DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5) -> works fine
4. DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4) -> works fine
5. DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3) -> InvalidDataException
6. DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) -> InvalidDataException
7. DateTime.Today.AddDays(100) -> InvalidDataException
8. DateTime.Today.AddDays(500) -> InvalidDataException
9. DateTime.Today.AddDays(1000) -> works fine

Reading [this 5 year-old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144781/powershell-backup-sqldatabase-expirationdate) it could be that the internal parameter is actually not of the type DateTime? But then it would be a bug, right?

Answer (score 0):

These errors are likely the result of the locale of where the `Backup.ExpirationDate` property is being set from.  Depending on the culture this is being executed in, the `DateTime.AddDays` method may increment the month instead of the day as expected, leading to the inconsistent results you saw.  Of the values that you tested only the negative ones should cause errors, as the range of days for a backup expiration date is 0 - 99999, with 0 indicating that the backup will never expire as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/set-the-expiration-date-on-a-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  Try using the `CultureInfo` class to define a new locale then set the expiration date.  This will require a reference to the `System.Globalization` namespace.  Running the following code gave me no errors in setting the expiration date in a backup operation using the US (`en-US`) culture.  Just make sure that the date in the culture you convert this to matches the date you expect it to in your timezone.

```
using System.Globalization;

            string folderPath = @"C:\YourFolder\";

            Server serv = new Server(@"YourServer");
            Backup bkup = new Backup();
            bkup.Database = "YourDatabase";

            string bkupFilePath = folderPath + bkup.Database.ToString() + ".bak";

            bkup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            bkup.Devices.AddDevice(bkupFilePath, DeviceType.File);
            bkup.BackupSetName = "YourDatabase Full Backup";
            bkup.BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of YourDatabase";

            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            //define current date representation with en-US culture
            string newLocale = today.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));

            //set Backup.ExpirationDate to use new culture
            bkup.ExpirationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(newLocale);

            bkup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(10);
            bkup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(100);
            bkup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(500);
            bkup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(1000);

            bkup.SqlBackup(serv);
```

Comment: Locale, that's a great idea, however, I tried this code `DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
                string newLocale = today.ToString(new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
                backup.ExpirationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(newLocale);
                backup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(100);` Same exception as before. The German locale should be correct for my system. I also tried en-US and en-EN just in case. Then the exception changes telling me ExpirationDate is not a valid DateTime. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried displaying a DateTime object using the AddDays function to see what this is being incremented to?

Comment: `bkup.ExpirationDate = bkup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(10);` This solved the issue. Apparently, AddDays does not modify the DateTime it is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* I am super confused. I thought this solved my issue:

> My issue was that I called `backup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(X)` without assigning it to anything. Therefore, the software was basically using "DateTime.Now".
>
> Solution:
> `backup.ExpirationDate = backup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(X);`

But it didn't completely. I still get the exception if I do this:

`backup.ExpirationDate = backup.ExpirationDate.AddDays(1);`

No idea why this code is wrong.